# how can i get the id of that particular comment i want to reply

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Below is the code I've written, I want to get particular id to reply the comment, how I can do that with below code. Please check my below snippet and suggest me the way I need to follow

```css
.anc {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a class="anc" data-toggle="modal" id="1" data-target="#add-reply">Reply 1</a>
<a class="anc" data-toggle="modal" id="2" data-target="#add-reply">Reply 2</a>
<a class="anc" data-toggle="modal" id="3" data-target="#add-reply">Reply 3</a>
<div class="modal fade modal-add-review" id="add-reply" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Reply</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <form class="comment-form" method="post">
          <p class="comment-notes">
            <span id="email-notes">
                Your email address will not be published.
            </span> Required fields are marked
            <span class="required">*</span>
          </p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group comment-form-author col-sm-6">
              <label for="author">Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
              <input class="form-control" id="reply_author" name="reply_author" type="text" required value="" placeholder="Enter your name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group comment-form-email col-sm-6">
              <label for="email">Email<span class="required">*</span></label>
              <input class="form-control" id="reply_email" name="reply_email" type="email" required value="" placeholder="Enter your email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group comment-form-comment">
            <label for="comment">Comment<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="reply_content" name="reply_content" required placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" name="create_reply" type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Submit
        </button>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You probably have multiple comments on one webpage and only one reply modal. In that case you have to transfer the comment id from the button to an hidden input in the form with Javascript. Give it a try.

Comment: yes i have multiple comments but its takes id of first comment everytime i reply. and thanks for replying . i dont know ajax or jquery . can u give exact code ?

Comment: Sorry, no, that's not how it works. You should at least show some effort on your part, a willingness to learn. You need Javascript or JQuery, and it probably won't be the last time. So, learn it.

Comment: im kinda new in this field , can u suggest good materials to learn java script

Comment: Try coding game or hackerrank. They are good site with concrete example and tutorial to help you learn.

Comment: Assuming you must have jQuery and the Bootstrap JS setup, then instead of using `data-toggle` use jQuery `on('click', ...)` and Bootstrap `$.modal('show')` code to open the modal and inject the `id`. Also use `data-id=""` instead of `id=""` as id is a HTML unique reference for that element. If you need an `id` as well, then prefix it with something sensible E.g. `id="comment-1"` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:-

```css
$('.commentBox').on('click', '.replyBtn', function(){
    $(this).parents('.commentBox');
})
```

```html
<div class="commentBox">
<div class="modal fade modal-add-review" id="add-reply" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title replyBtn">Reply</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

           <-- MODAL REPLY FORM -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>      
</div>
```

Comment: its still taking the first comment id

Comment: its fetching through the while loop to show all comments

Comment: can you share your code with loop actually i want to know that where loop is running.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pWgcB2ybOBmOVKCetQwkMatlRQiDUAg0/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I create a function called `addId` with `id` parameter and add it to `onclick` of all `a` tags. when the user clicks on `a` tag `addId` function will invoke and set id to a hidden input.

```js
 function getId(id){
   document.getElementById("commentId").value = id;
 }
```

```css
.anc {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a class="anc" onClick="getId(1)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add-reply">Reply 1</a>
<a class="anc" onClick="getId(2)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add-reply">Reply 2</a>
<a class="anc" onClick="getId(3)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add-reply">Reply 3</a>
<div class="modal fade modal-add-review" id="add-reply" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Reply</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <form class="comment-form" method="post">
          <p class="comment-notes">
            <span id="email-notes">
                Your email address will not be published.
            </span> Required fields are marked
            <span class="required">*</span>
          </p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group comment-form-author col-sm-6">
              <label for="author">Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
              <input class="form-control" id="reply_author" name="reply_author" type="text" required value="" placeholder="Enter your name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group comment-form-email col-sm-6">
              <label for="email">Email<span class="required">*</span></label>
              <input class="form-control" id="reply_email" name="reply_email" type="email" required value="" placeholder="Enter your email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group comment-form-comment">
            <label for="comment">Comment<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="reply_content" name="reply_content" required placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>
          </div>
          <input type="hidden" id="commentId" name="id">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" name="create_reply" type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Submit
        </button>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```